# Is it possible to run mulitple zoom on d3

Tags: d3.js, zooming

I am trying to have a trend that can be zoomed via canvas and via each axis. 
The canvas should zoom all axis and the single axis zoom should only zoom itself.

So far so good.

Now I want the canvas only to zoom selected axis. But when I reselect and deselected axis it jumps by zooming to the current scale.

I thought about adding the zoom of evry axis to the canvas, but

```html
canvas.call(zoom1).call(zoom2);
```

will only call the last one.

Does anyone has any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an other way to zoom multiple axis and the global zoom.

The following example is without canvas but should work the same way:

https://jsfiddle.net/DaWa/wnxu7m04/3/

The difference to the solutions before is, that

```
the scale will be adapted when changing the zoom selection 
that all rects ecpet of rect which calls the zoom will be reset.
```

I know that this solution is a bit hacky but currently there is no official solution (see https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/48)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by calling the zoom function of the according group.

```
See https://jsfiddle.net/DaWa/3jfs6zb1/2/
```

Now I have tha problem, that the two transforms (the global and the single axis) do not adapt to each other.

Any ideas?